# Hard drive won't power on, is this the reason why?

Tags: pcb, hardware, diy, damage, hard-drive

I have a somewhat old, but functional (used to be, actually) hard drive, model Samsung HD103SJ, which I use for backup purposes. This means this is not a fixed unit.

Since a few weeks ago when I moved to a new city, I notice it wouldn't power on anymore. So, upon closer inspection, I noticed one component hanging "loose" in its PCB:

[image: pcb scan]

The component is labeled 4R7V. It appears to be actually connected... Here's a look on the opposite side:

[image: component underside]

My questions:

- is it an inductor?
- is it the reason why the hard drive is non-functional? Is it reasonable to expect to fix the problem by replacing it?

Comment: Replace it : you may be lucky and it works... does the drive live in an external box? If you get it to work , consider an enclosure for it...

Comment: Good job on the question. Nice picture.

Comment: I don't think your pic is fuzzy enough. Maybe put it through a gaussian filter or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an inductor. Probably it is why the drive is non-functional. It is reasonable to expect that the drive will function again after you replace it, though there are no guarantees. I assume 4R7 means that it is 4.7uH, but I could be wrong.

Comment: As an update, I soldered it again and it indeed worked (and is still functional to this day).